# Not displaying error message for a select drop down in Struts 2

Tags: jsp, struts2, struts-validation

I have following code

**`Action`:**

```java
private String yourSearchEngine;
private String selectedUserGroupId;   

//with both getter and setter.

public void validate(){
    if("-1".equals(getYourSearchEngine())){
        addFieldError("yourSearchEngine", getText("select search engine"));
        addressList.add("Select search engine");
    }

    if("-1".equals(getSelectedUserGroupId())){
        addFieldError("selectedUserGroupId", "select user group");
        addressList.add("Select user group");
    }
```

**JSP page:**

```jsp
<s:select   label="Search engine:" 
            headerKey="-1" 
            headerValue="Select Search Engines"
            list="searchEngine" 
            name="yourSearchEngine" 
            id="yourSearchEngine"
            value="defaultSearchEngine" 
            tooltip="Select Search Engines" />
            
<s:select   label = "User Group:" 
            list = "userGroupList" 
            listKey = "userGroupId"
            listValue = "userGroup"
            name = "selectedUserGroupId"
            id="selectedUserGroupId"
            headerKey="-1" 
            headerValue="Select Group" 
            tooltip="Select Group" ></s:select>
```

when I submit the form and value is `-1`, it is not display error message.

I can see that `addFieldError` code run `addressList` get populated.

But is not displaying the error message.

Answer (score 0):

By default Struts2 uses `xhtml` theme. This theme is designed to display field errors on input elements bound to the action. If errors aren't displayed then make sure you have used `xhtml` theme, or you can add explicitely `theme` attribute to each select tag or to the form tag. You can also configure a theme to be used by default using struts constant.

```jsp
<s:select   label="Search engine:" 
            headerKey="-1" 
            headerValue="Select Search Engines"
            list="searchEngine" 
            name="yourSearchEngine" 
            id="yourSearchEngine"
            value="defaultSearchEngine" 
            tooltip="Select Search Engines" 
            theme="xhtml" />

<s:select   label = "User Group:" 
            list = "userGroupList" 
            listKey = "userGroupId"
            listValue = "userGroup"
            name = "selectedUserGroupId"
            id="selectedUserGroupId"
            headerKey="-1" 
            headerValue="Select Group" 
            tooltip="Select Group" 
            theme="xhtml" />
```

See where you can specify a `theme` in struts tags. [Specifying The Theme Struts 2 Should Use](https://struts.apache.org/getting-started/themes.html#specifying-the-theme-struts-2-should-use).

> You can specify the theme on a per Struts 2 tag basis or you can use one of the following methods to specify what theme Struts 2 should use:

- The `theme` attribute on the specific tag
- The `theme` attribute on a tag's surrounding form tag
- The page-scoped attribute named `"theme"`
- The request-scoped attribute named `"theme"`
- The session-scoped attribute named `"theme"`
- The application-scoped attribute named `"theme"`
- The `struts.ui.theme` property in `struts.properties` (defaults to `xhtml`)

To make this effective on the page make sure the `INPUT` result configured to the action with `defaultStack` of interceptors.